# Mongodb query, that returns documents that doesn't have a field specified in searched query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have following documents in Mongo DB.

```
{"brand" : "BMW", "year" : 2016, "color" : "red" }
{"brand" : "BMW", "year" : 2000, "color" : "white" }
{"brand" : "BMW", "year" : 2010 }
```

I would like to make a query like:

```
db.collection.find({ "brand" : "BMW", "color" : "red" })
```

and obtain this results:

```
{"brand" : "BMW", "year" : 2016, "color" : "red" }
{"brand" : "BMW", "year" : 2010 }
```

A red car was returned because the query specified this.

At the same time I would like to have in same result, documents that doesn't have 'color' field at all (because may be this car also is red, but it is not specified in document).

Is it possible to get this results in a single query?

I would like to make this query using **Spring Data for Mongo**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply try like this by adding `$or` condition for - either `color` is `red` or `color` not `exists`

```
db.collection.find({ "brand" : "BMW", $or: [ { "color": "red" }, { "color": { $exists: false } } ] })
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
> db.foo.find({$or : [ {"brand": "BMW"}, {$and: [ { "brand" : "BMW"}, {"color": {$exists: 1}}   ]} ] })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58272b4279180900222235ea"), "brand" : "BMW", "year" : 2016, "color" : "red" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58272b4e79180900222235eb"), "brand" : "BMW", "year" : 2000, "color" : "white" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58272b5c79180900222235ec"), "brand" : "BMW", "year" : 2010 }
>
```

i'm specific querying for either cars with brand bmw OR cars with brand bmw AND they have a color field as well.

if you need to look for a specific color, you can change this part in my query above:

```
{"color": {$exists: 1}}
```

to:

```
{"color": "something"}
```

Comment: your query returns `58272b4e79180900222235eb` I guess the author doesn't mean that.

Comment: @alfredopacino i'm not sure what you have setup, but i created a collection, added the documents he used as examples, then ran the query and results from that query. not sure how you got what you got.

Comment: I meant: `58272b4e79180900222235eb` is your white BMW, I think the author doesn't want it in the result set.

Comment: @alfredopacino got it. this is why i added the extra info about if you want more specific than a document that just has a 'color' field, you can be more specific that that in the 'and' clause of the query. thanks for the questions.

Answer (score 0):

if I get the problem:

```
db.foo.find(
{$or :[
        {"brand": "BMW","color" : "red"},
        {$and:[
             { "brand" : "BMW"},
             {"color": { $exists: false} }
        ]}
]})
```